# How to repair porcelain sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub

I have a chip and some rust in my porcelain sink.

How do I repair this and is this causing water leaking?

[image]

I was thinking to use a wire-brush to brush out the rust and use porcelain paint to repaint the porcelain.

Is that a good idea? Do I need to remove the sink drain?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any evidence of water leaking?

Comment: Thankfully not. I guess if this continues, it will start?

Comment: A wire brush would exacerbate the apparent chrome loss on the drain  fitting (which gets my attention more than the rust in the chipped porcelain) more than a gentler alternative.

Comment: The damage shown, if left untreated, will eventually rust through the underlying metal and cause a leak. The sink appears to be cast iron, so this will take anywhere from eighty years to two centuries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wire brush is too large for these small spots. You would damage the area around it. You do not have to remove the drain.

First clean the whole area with whatever mild abrasive cleaner you have been using. Scrub carefully with cleaning powder and a soft cloth. Get the abrasive powder out of the rust, then dry with a cloth.

Then put a dab of porcelain paint on it as is. Or try to remove the rust with a very abrasive eraser stick (like we used to use with a typewriter) and then put on the paint. The paint color will not match and will show, but it will look better than the rust and the rust will be stopped for a long time.

Comment: Maybe mention a lime-n-rust cleaner?